# spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a pyspark job using yarn with the spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true option but the job never completes :

Without the option, the job works well:

```
user@e7524bf7f996:~$ pyspark --master yarn                                                               
Using Python version 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021 13:09:58)
Spark context Web UI available at http://e7524bf7f996:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1644937120225_0004).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> sc.parallelize(range(10)).sum()
45
```

With the option --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true

```
user@e7524bf7f996:~$ pyspark --master yarn --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
Using Python version 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021 13:09:58)
Spark context Web UI available at http://e7524bf7f996:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1644937120225_0005).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> sc.parallelize(range(10)).sum()
2022-02-15 15:10:14,591 WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2022-02-15 15:10:29,590 WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
2022-02-15 15:10:44,591 WARN cluster.YarnScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Are there other options in Spark or Yarn that should be enabled to make spark.shuffle.service.enabled work ?

I am running Spark 3.1.2 , Python 3.9.7, hadoop-3.2.1

Thank you,

Bertrand

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure external shuffle service on Yarn cluster by following

1. Build Spark with the YARN profile. Skip this step if you are using a
   pre-packaged distribution.
2. Locate the
   `spark-<version>-yarn-shuffle.jar`. This should be under
   $SPARK_HOME/common/network-yarn/target/scala- if you are
   building Spark yourself, and under yarn if you are using a
   distribution.
3. Add this jar to the classpath of all NodeManagers in
   your cluster.
4. In the `yarn-site.xml` on each node, add spark_shuffle
   to `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`, then set
   `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.spark_shuffle.class` to
   `org.apache.spark.network.yarn.YarnShuffleService`.
5. Increase
   NodeManager's heap size by setting `YARN_HEAPSIZE` (1000 by default)
   in `etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh` to avoid garbage collection issues during
   shuffle.
6. Restart all NodeManagers in your cluster.

For details, please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service

If still not working, check below:

1. Check Yarn UI to ensure enough resources available.
2. Try `--deploy-mode cluster` to ensure driver could communicate    with yarn cluster for scheduling

Comment: Thanks Warren for your help.
I followed the steps but the spark job hangs and no resources are allocated to the jobs.

Here is my :

Comment: yarn-site.xml:

`    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>
      $HADOOP_CONF_DIR, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*, $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*, $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,\
 $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*, $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,/home/user/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/yarn/* ,/home/user/spark-3.1.2-\
bin-hadoop3.2/yarn/spark-3.1.2-yarn-shuffle.jar
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle,spark_shuffle</value>
`

Comment: I followed all the other steps but the job does not get any resources.

Comment: Could put full yarn-site.xml in question desc?

Comment: Following this page : https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=sf000078677en_us&docLocale=en_US

I changed the yarn-site.xml to :

https://github.com/BertrandBrelier/SparkYarn/blob/main/yarn-site.xml

But I got the same results : no resources are allocated to the spark job launched with:

pyspark --master yarn --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true

I checked that Spark Yarn Shuffle Service is running

user@8aa2d34c410a:~$ lsof -i:7337
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    1275 user  383u  IPv4 6566531      0t0  TCP *:7337 (LISTEN)

Comment: I also created a link:

ln -s /home/user/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/yarn/spark-3.1.2-yarn-shuffle.jar /home/user/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/.

and set

spark.shuffle.service.enabled    true 

in spark-defaults.conf

Comment: Your yarn-site.xml looks good. Then you can check 2 things I added in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Warren for your help.

Here is the setup working for me:

https://github.com/BertrandBrelier/SparkYarn/blob/main/yarn-site.xml

```
echo "export YARN_HEAPSIZE=2000" >> /home/user/hadoop-3.2.1/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh

ln -s /home/user/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/yarn/spark-3.1.2-yarn-shuffle.jar /home/user/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/.

echo "spark.shuffle.service.enabled    true" >> /home/user/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

restarting Hadoop and Spark

I was able to start a pyspark session:

```
pyspark --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
```